# How to reuse the window (or close the current one) when hitting the Run button?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx

I'm using IntelliJ to run my app. Is there a way to relaunch the window or close the current one when hitting the run button?

This is because when I hit the run button it creates a new window every time. It gets a bit tedious/confusing to close the previous window that is running old code.

[image]

Comment: There’s a setting for that in IntelliJ but I’m away from computer. You can search for settings in the IDE.

Comment: I've tried "Open project in the same window" https://i.imgur.com/Vp3Ph0n.png and "Terminate process" but neither work. I'm assuming that's for the Java project. I'm not quite sure what to search for the app

Comment: What run configuration is in use? if the IDE can control the application, it should prevent running it again until it is stopped.

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov current configurations: https://i.imgur.com/9u6Jkuq.png

Comment: Still can't figure out how to do it :/

Comment: @Tenfour04 any update on where this Setting is in the IDE?

Comment: I didn't know you were still asking me questions because you didn't @ me before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the *Run* menu and select *Edit configurations...*

Select the configuration you've been using to run your project in the left panel. Either it's the Gradle `yourProjectName:desktop [run]` task, or it's an Application run configuration you've created yourself.

Uncheck the box that says "Allow parallel run".

The next time you try to run it when it's already running, it will warn you that it can only run it if it kills the old process. You can check a box in this dialog to do that automatically from now on.

I've never figured a way to toggle this behavior back to how it was, but I've rarely ever needed to compare two builds side-by-side.

Comment: I just saw in your screen shot in the comments that *Allow parallel run* is not checked, so that's weird! Do you really need to use a custom run configuration, though? For most purposes, you can just use the Gradle desktop->run task.

Comment: No I don't need a custom run configuration but the video tutorial I was following set one up. Where is the Gradle desktop -> run task option? And yes Allow parallel run is not checked I just tried it with and without it checked and both are still creating a new window everytime I hit run

Comment: By default, there's tab along the right side of the IntelliJ window with a Gradle tab. (If it's not there, go to View->Tool Windows->Gradle.) Open that Gradle tool window, and expand the tree to find desktop->Tasks->other->run. Double-click it to run it the first time. Then it will be in the run configurations.

Comment: Found it, but that still creates multiple windows though

Comment: Okay, after running it once, the run option changed to ```MyApp:desktop [run]``` and when hitting run it again it created a dialog and asked if I wanted to stop and rerun. (Which prevented multiple windows from creating)